# Dates and Math in PHP

Tags: php, base64, strtotime, date-math

I am granting paid members of a site the ability to share premium content with non-members for a period of 30 days. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

First, the subscriber fills out a form to generate an email to their buddy, which generates a URL for the content landing page. Because I don't want them to **easily** be able to manipulate this, all I did is append a base64 encoded date to the landing page URL.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/video_landing_page.php?" . base64_encode(date('Y-m-d'));
```

The recipient would receive a link that looks like http://www.example.com/video_landing_page.php?MjAxNC0wMi0yNg==

On the landing page, I parsed the url to grab just the query and decoded it:

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$url_components = parse_url($url);
$query = $url_components['query'];
$decodedQuery = base64_decode($query);
```

Now I want to display an error message if 30 days have passed since the url was created, and this is where I am stuck. I have tried like this and failed to get what I needed:

```
if ((strtotime($decodedQuery) + strtotime('+30 Days')) > date('Y-m-d){
    Display error Message
} else {
    Display Success Message
}
```

But the math isn't coming out right. Any ideas? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas?

You're comparing a Unix Timstamp to a string. That won't work (like you expect).

```
if ((strtotime($decodedQuery) + strtotime('+30 Days')) > date('Y-m-d){
```

should be:

```
if ((strtotime($decodedQuery) + strtotime('+30 Days')) > time()){
```

This compares two Unix Timestamps.

> Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Yes. Use `DateTime()` as they are comparible:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$inOneMonth = new DateTime($decodedQuery);
$inOneMonth->modify('+1 month');
if ($inOneMonth > $now){
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `base64()` which can be *easily manipulated*, instead, store a unique `id` in your Database, store the date on which the record was created. Now use this `id` for creating urls instead of using date, will also save you few bytes per record as well.

Now when the user visits, fetch the date from the database using that unique `id` and use `strtotime()` to compare with the current time.

---

For example... Assume that Mr. X got a URL like

```
http://demo.com/landingpage.php?uid=454566
```

On `landingpage.php` use..

```
$store_id = (isset($_GET['uid'])) ? $_GET['uid'] : ''; 
// Validate, fetch the row from DB and count, if not 1 than throw error, 
// if it returns one than go ahead

// Or you can use INTERVAL 30 DAY < NOW() if you want MySQL to do the job for you
// Than just compare the row count.. or if you want to do with PHP

if(strtotime($fetched_db_time) < strtotime('-30 days')){
    //Record is 30 days older
}
```

You can also create your own hashing mechanism for this by replacing the numbers with letters, but it is better if you use the unique ID concept, as you don't have to leak out your data in the url with lose encoding.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(strtotime($decodedQuery) + strtotime('+30 Days')` Results to the current date plus 30 days as seconds plus the time of the decoded query in seconds.
2. Your comparing seconds since epoch to a string

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(strtotime($decodedQuery.' + 30 Days')  > date('Y-m-d) )
```

but yeah, `base64` is weak

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if (strtotime($decodedQuery) < strtotime('-30 Days')) {
 //$decodedQuery is more than 30 days in the past
}
```